# Bug with submit() event

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#old_thumb').click(function(){
            $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
            $('#sf').val('2');
            $('#add_new_event').submit();
        });
    });
    //-->
</script>
```

For some reason the `submit()` is not working (my form doesn't submit after I click the old_thumb button. Can any one help me?

here is part of the html (its very long and its included php so I will write only the start and those fields which I update )..

```
<form action="http://dominicbesner.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ManageMedia/MM-admin.php&action=Edit2" method="post"  name="add_new_event" id="add_new_event" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="sf" id="sf" value="1" />
    <input type="button" name="old_thumb" id="old_thumb" value="Edit" title="<?php echo $file;?>'" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save Medias" class="button-primary" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset Form" class="button" /></td>
</form>
```

Comment: what does console show? any debug, error or warnings?

Comment: Nothing wrong at console .. the script is working it just doesn't submit the form :/ If I put more jquery code after submit() its working..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - form won't submit using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513055/jquery-form-wont-submit-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing your jQuery instance references - you're using `jQuery` and `$`. Assuming you've set `noConflict` try this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#old_thumb').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).attr('title'));
        jQuery('#sf').val('2');
        jQuery('#add_new_event').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I fix that but its not working yet (added part of the html from the form)..
The changes of val() are working but submitting is not..

Comment: If you put the following code in there what happens: `alert(jQuery('#add_new_event').length);`

Comment: I put it directly after the submit() on next line and it alert me - 1

Comment: Do you have any other code on the page which is attached to the `submit()` event on your form - jQuery validate for example?

Comment: No the script is clean from ajax.
How ever .. I made one change (type of button to submit) so now its submiting.. this will work for now :) 
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working with earlier versions of jQuery (< 1.7).

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function"
```

See [release notes for 1.7.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/21/jquery-1-7-1-released/).

[10844](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10844) and [10701](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10701) includes issues with submitting forms.

Also, while using an earlier version of jQuery your target page sends the header `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` causing this error: *Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.*" (at least at jsFiddle where iFrames are used).

Answer (score 0):

1) why do you have remarked you r code ?

2) what version of jQuery you use ?

3) remove the  jQuery('#old_thumb').click(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
        $('#sf').val('2');
        $('#add_new_event').submit();
        });

out of the document ready func

4)what is $('#add_new_event') ? what kind of element ?

Comment: I add those fields at my first post(html code to see how looks part of my form.. 
I don't see how it will work if I move it out of the document ready function

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem however I was using a button element (with the id "submit") to pop up a jQuery dialog before submitting the form.  On clicking on one of the dialog buttons I tried to submit the form -

```
$("#myform").submit();
```

However it always gave the error -

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object # is not a function

When I changed the ID of the button to something else the form submitted fine.

Not the best fix I'm aware but I thought it might help.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably already answered but the issue that's triggering the error is the fact that you are invoking the "submit()" event on a form element.

Instead of doing this:

```
$("#myform").submit();
```

Call a function that will handle your submit. Here's my code for my form submission. Fell free to copy/modify/use to your liking:

```
$('#submit').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Check for a Name
    if($('#name').val() !== '') {
        $('#name').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#name').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
    }

    // Check for a Valid Email
    if(isEmail($('#email').val())) {
        $('#email').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#email').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
    }

    // Check for a Valid Phone number
    if(isPhoneNumber($('#phone').val())) {
    $('#phone').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
    } else {
    $('#phone').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
    }

    // Check for a Message
    if($('#message').val() !== ''){
        $('#message').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
    } else {
    $('#message').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
    }

    // Check to see if Any input/textarea has the class 'error'
    if($('input').hasClass('error') || $('textarea').hasClass('error')){
        // Invalid form entry
    } else {
        // Submit the form
        submitForm();
    }
});
```

I have two functions to check for a valid email and valid phone number

```
function isEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}

function isPhoneNumber(number) {
    var regex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    return regex.test(number);
}
```

Then I have the function to handle the form submission

```
function submitForm() {
    toggleModal(false);
    // Format the data
    var data = 'name=' + $('#name').val() + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&phone=' + $('#phone').val() + '&message=' + encodeURIComponent($('#message').val());
    // start the ajax
    $.ajax({
        // this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
        url: "process.php",
        // GET method is used
        type: "GET",
        // pass the data
        data: data,
        // Do not cache the page
        cache: false,
        // Success response
        success: function (html) {
            $('#contact-form').fadeOut('slow', function(e) {
                toggleModal(false);
                if (html==1) {
                    // if process.php returned 1/true (show success message)
                    // show the success message
                    $('#success').fadeIn('slow');
                } else {
                    // if process.php returned 0/false (show failed message)
                    //Show Fail Message
                    $('#fail').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });
        }       
    });
}
```