# jQuery - form won't submit using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Further to my problem here - [jQuery on submit validation, with modal dialog at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502578/jquery-on-submit-validation-with-modal-dialog-at-the-end)

It seems like the form simply will not submit using jQuery. Here's my code at a very simplified level:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).click(function() {
            $('#inputform').submit();
        });

        $("#inputform").submit(function() {
            alert('test');
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo CURRENT_PAGE ?>" id="inputform">

<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit form</button>

</form>
```

Clicking on the body displays the 'test' alert but doesn't submit the form. Also, upon closing the alert box, it won't re-appear when you click again.

Simply clicking on the submit button itself displays the alert then submits the form as expected.

Sorry for what is (I know) a really stupid question, but I'm at a loss here. TY!

Comment: remove `$("#inputform").submit(function() {return true;});`

Comment: @ tj - sorry! I tried adding it in but it kept messing with the formatting above. @ mgraph - thank you, but I have a lot of validation in there

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that you've given your submit button the name "submit". Change it to just about anything else and it'll work. (Also change the `id`, best to keep them the same, not least because of [some browser issues](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html).)

Why: Form elements have a property called `submit` which is the function you can call to submit them. (jQuery uses this under the covers when you call `submit` on the jQuery instance.) But Form elements *also* receive properties for each of the fields in the form, using the field's name, and so if you have a field called "submit", it *overrides* the `submit` function, which means you can't submit the form programmatically.

Working example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/iforoc) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/iforoc/edit)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).click(function() {
            $('#inputform').submit();
        });

        $("#inputform").submit(function() {
            alert('test');
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>

<form method="GET" action="http://jsbin.com/uwuzon" id="inputform">
<input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">
<button type="submit" name="someOtherName" id="someOtherName">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

(The significant change is the `name="someOtherName" id="someOtherName"` part. The other changes [changing the form's action and method] are just so it works on JSbin.)

Side note: You don't have to `return true;` in your `submit` event handler to allow the form submission. You just have to *not* `return false;`. :-)

Comment: This is working perfectly now, thank you so much! I never knew having the name and id of submit would cause so many problems :$

Comment: @xndx: :-) Good deal, glad that helped!

Comment: This drove me nuts. Great advice @T.J.Crowder. Fixed my bug too.