# Input name submit not submit the form

Tags: php, html

If I name button to "submit" the form is not submitting. But If I changed the name something else the form is submitting.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form name="my_form" action="/search" method="get" id="my_form">
/** code **/
<button name="submit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
</form>
```

Here If I change `button` name somthing else then it will work and submit the form.

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.attr_list').on('ifChanged', function(event){
        alert("message will display"); // here alert will come but form is not submitting
        $("#my_form").submit();
    });
});
```

**Why it is not submitting if I named the button to "submit" ?**

Comment: `$('.attr_list').on('ifChanged', function(event){` where is the code relate to the `attr_list`.please post your full code

Comment: Please attach full code, specially how `.attr_list` comes.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: .attr_list thats does not matter. If i alert anything on  $('.attr_list').on('ifChanged', function(event ) it is displaying alert message. But form is not submitting

Comment: i think your select box (attr_list) is out of the form? isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - form won't submit using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513055/jquery-form-wont-submit-using-jquery)

Comment: And known bug: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4652

Comment: @David, please check my answer if that works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change your button name from "submit" to anything else.

**Reason:**

Form elements have a property called `submit` which is the function you can call to submit them. (jQuery uses this under the covers when you call `submit` on the jQuery instance.) But Form elements also receive properties for each of the fields in the form, using the field's name, and so if you have a field called "submit", it overrides the `submit` function, which means you can't submit the form programmatically.

**Your code should be:**

```
<form name="my_form" action="/search" method="get" id="my_form">
/** code **/
<button name="othername" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
</form>
```

It will work....

Answer (score 0):

You can also try :

```
$("form").submit(function(){
     alert("Submitted");
});
```

instead of   `$("#my_form").submit();` if it is creating issues

Answer (score -1):

Is there any ob_start() available in your file. Please remove it and try once.

Comment: Contrary to the use of the tag "php" in the question, this question doesn't involve any PHP and it doesn't sound like the HTML is not being displayed correctly (which is what `ob_start()` would supposedly do).

Comment: This is not an answer and should have been a comment. The question in it should have a question mark, not a dot as if it were just a sentence.